# SQL Query not working in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I am just trying to run an update query using codeigniter using an array. Here is my code

```
$array = array('departmentID' => $departmentID);
    $this->db->where($array);
    $data = array(
        "pending" => "pending+".$pendingNew,
        "approved" => "approved+".$approvedNew,
        "notApproved" => "notApproved+".$notApprovedNew
    );
    $this->db->update('departments', $data);
```

It is running fine and not giving any errors but it is not updating the database, so I tried printing out the generated query like this

`echo $this->db->last_query();`

And it gives me the following

```
UPDATE `departments` SET `pending` = 'pending+2', `approved` = 'approved+6', `notApproved` = 'notApproved+0' WHERE `departmentID` = '10';
```

So I believe the problem is because it is putting the apostophes around the addition part as when I remove those and just run the sql as the floowing it updates coreectly.

```
UPDATE `departments` SET `pending` = pending+2, `approved` = approved+6, `notApproved` = notApproved+0 WHERE `departmentID` = '10'
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try updating the values this way, it works for me

```
$this->db->set('pending', 'pending + ' . (int) $pendingNew,  false);
$this->db->set('approved', 'approved  + ' . (int) $approvedNew,  false);
$this->db->where($array);
$this->db->update('departments');
```

Comment: @DavidFarrelly if worked please accept this users answer.